Could this closed-form expression for the integral of the Riemann $\xi$-function along the critical line provide new insights?
The Riemann $\xi$ and $\Xi$-functions are respectively defined as:
\begin{align} 
\xi(s) &= \frac{s\,(s-1)}{2}\, \pi^{-s/2} \,\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\,\right) \zeta(s) \qquad s \in \mathbb{C} \\
\Xi(t) &=\xi\left(\frac12 +it\right) \qquad \qquad \qquad \,\,\,\quad t \in \mathbb{C}\\
\end{align}
The Fourier cosine integral expression for $\Xi(t)$ and its inverse are:
\begin{align}
\Xi(t) &=\,\,2\,\int_0^\infty \Phi(x)\,\cos(xt)\, \mathrm{d} x  \tag{1} \\
\Phi(t) &=\frac{1}{\pi}\,\int_0^\infty \Xi(x)\,\cos(xt)\, \mathrm{d} x    \tag{2}
\end{align}
where $\Phi$ is the super-exponentially decaying even function:
\begin{align}
 \Phi(u) = \Phi(-u) =2\,\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2\,\pi^2  n^4 e^{9u/2} - 3\,\pi\, n^2 e^{5u/2} ) \exp(-\pi\, n^2 e^{2u} ).
\end{align}
Setting $t=0$ in (2) yields:
$$\int_0^\infty \Xi(x)\, \mathrm{d} x = \pi\,\Phi(0) = \pi\left(2\,\theta''(1)+3\,\theta'(1)\right) \tag{3}$$
where $\displaystyle \theta(x) =\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \exp(-n^2\pi\,x)$, the well-known 3rd Jacobi theta function.
In 2018, Romik published The Taylor coefficients of the Jacobi theta constant $\theta_3$ and provided us with closed forms for $\theta''(1)$ and higher derivatives (see end of post). We can now simply derive the (new?) closed form for the integral over the critical line that is unconditional on the RH:
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\int_0^\infty \Xi\left(x\right)\mathrm{d}x = \Gamma\left(\frac14\right)\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)^8-96\,\pi^4}{256\,\sqrt{2}\,\pi^{15/4}}} \tag{4}
\end{equation}
In 2011, Lagarias and Montague published the paper The integral of the Riemann $\xi$-function, in which they label the RHS of (3) as $A_0$ (i.e. not the closed form) and observe:

Question: Does such an arithmetic interpretation of the RHS of (4) exist? Is there any new information about $\Xi(t)$ we could derive from the closed form?
Additionally, the same questions could be asked about this related MO-question: Xi Function on Critical Strip - Mellin Transform, that deals with the slightly amended integral (already known by Titchmarsh):
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\Xi(x)}{x^2 + \frac{1}{4}} \cos(xt) dx = \frac{1}{2} \pi (e^{\frac{1}{2}t} - 2e^{-\frac{1}{2}t} \psi(e^{-2t})) \tag{5}$$
where $\displaystyle \psi(x)=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} e^{-n^2 \pi x}$. This has an even simpler closed form (using $\psi(1) = \left(\theta(1)-1\right)/2)$:
\begin{align}
 \int_0^\infty \frac{\Xi(x)}{x^2 + \frac{1}{4}} dx &= \pi \left(\frac12 -\psi(1) \right)\\
 &= \pi \left(1 - \frac12\,\theta(1)\right)\\
 &= \pi \left(1-\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)}{2\,\sqrt{2}\,\pi^{\frac14}}\right)\tag{6}\\
\end{align}
EDIT: using the closed forms for higher derivatives from Romik's paper, we also have:
\begin{align}
\scriptsize{ \int_0^\infty \Xi(x)\,x^0\, \mathrm{d}x} &= \scriptsize{\pi\Phi^{(0)}(0) = \,\,\,\,\frac{2\,\pi^{21/4}}{32\,\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)^{9}}\,\,\,\,-\frac{3\,\pi^{5/4}}{8\,\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)} } \\
\scriptsize{-\int_0^\infty \Xi(x)\,x^2\, \mathrm{d}x} &= \scriptsize{\pi\Phi^{(2)}(0) = -\frac{2\,\pi^{37/4}}{256\,\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)^{17}}\,\,-\frac{45\,\pi^{21/4}}{64\,\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)^9}\,\,\,\,\,+\frac{15\,\pi^{5/4}}{16\,\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)} } \\
\scriptsize{\,\int_0^\infty \Xi(x)\,x^4\, \mathrm{d}x} &= \scriptsize{\pi\Phi^{(4)}(0)= \,\frac{102\,\pi^{53/4}}{2048\,\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)^{25}}\,\,+\frac{191\,\pi^{37/4}}{512\,\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)^{17}}\,+\frac{1800\,\pi^{21/4}}{128\,\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)^9} \,\,\,\,\,- \frac{285\,\pi^{5/4}}{32\,\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)}} \\ 
\scriptsize{-\int_0^\infty \Xi(x)\,x^6\, \mathrm{d}x} &=\scriptsize{ \pi\Phi^{(6)}(0) = \frac{1698\,\pi^{69/4}}{16348\,\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)^{33}}-\frac{25755\,\pi^{53/4}}{4096\,\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)^{25}}-\frac{21683\,\pi^{37/4}}{1024\,\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)^{17}} - \frac{118305\,\pi^{21/4}}{256\,\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)^9}+\frac{11085\,\pi^{5/4}}{64\,\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)}} \\
\cdots \quad \quad & \cdots \qquad \cdots\\
\end{align}
The first expression simply reworks equation (4) into a more comparable form. All odd derivatives are obviously zero. A pattern seems to form, but the resulting integer coefficients are quite intricate. For instance the integers in the numerators in the first column are twice the mysterious A317651-sequence.
